# How to rewrite this variable in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have this code snippet that i want to modify a bit

```
uint256 public constant decimals = 9;

uint256 private constant DECIMALS = 9;
uint256 private constant MAX_UINT256 = ~uint256(0);
uint256 private constant INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY = 10**9 * 10**DECIMALS;

uint256 private constant TOTAL_GONS = MAX_UINT256 - (MAX_UINT256 % INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY);

uint256 private constant MAX_SUPPLY = ~uint128(0);  // (2^128) - 1

uint256 private _totalSupply;
uint256 private _gonsPerFragment;
mapping(address => uint256) private _gonBalances;

mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowedFragments;
```

What i try to achieve is make this code work with a totalsupply of 300 Token, this code produces 1 billion token.
Im asking about the line

```
uint256 private constant INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY = 10**9 * 10**DECIMALS;
```

this cretes a contract with 1 billion token, how can i change it to produce 300 token?
I tried this

```
uint256 private constant INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY = 300;
```

and I also tried

```
uint256 private constant INITIAL_FRAGMENTS_SUPPLY = 300 * 1**DECIMALS;
```

But it somehow doesnt work the way i want to, it creates 300 coins but when i call the burn function and burn 1 Token- i can see that the totalSupply is 299 token but i dont see the decimals that are beeing burned.

So basically if i have 1000 token with 10 tokenholders that hold 100 token each, after i burn 100 token everyone only holds 90 token.

Now if I have only 300 token and 300 token holders- the tokenholders should have after the burn about 0.998 token or so but when i ran it in remix, the balance still shows 1 token

Comment: `300 * 10**decimals`

Comment: And get rid of `DECIMALS` while you're at it.

Comment: this gives me a total supply of 3billion plus 9 zeros, whats wrong with DECIMALS?

Comment: `300 * 10**decimals` gives you a total supply of 300 tokens **by the definition of the ERC20 standard**!!!

Comment: There are several things wrong with `DECIMALS`, the first of which is that you already have the same constant value in `decimals`, and if you know anything about programming, then you should know that redundancy is always a bad thing. This has nothing to do with Ethereum BTW, it's a general (and very fundamental) programming concept.

Comment: The second thing that's wrong is that the ERC20 standard defines `decimals`, not `DECIMALS`, so if you want your token to comply with the standard then you must implement `decimals` (as a public variable or function). Now that you understand why you must have `decimals` in your contract, go back to my previous comment and conclude why you should not have `DECIMALS` in it.

Comment: thanks dude, but if i use 300 *10** decimals i get a total supply of 300000000000

Comment: Which is exactly 300 tokens, according to the value that you chose for `decimals` in your contract!

Comment: One more time - in an ERC20 Token contract, `300 * 10**decimals` defines 300 tokens, **regardless** of the value of `decimals`. This is **by the definition of the ERC20 standard**. The value of `decimals` determines only **the resolution** of your token. For example, if you set it to 0 (`totalSupply == 300`), then you can transfer only whole units (e.g., 12 tokens, 25 tokens, etc). Whereas, if you set it to `1` (`totalSupply == 3000`), then you can transfer "tenth units" (e.g., 12.3 tokens, 25.7 tokens, etc).

Comment: well, i know the question i have is if i deploy this contract and list it on uniswap- will my total supply be 300 or 300 9decimals? I also uncommented the DECIMALS line

Comment: 300 tokens, and 300000000000 basic units (aka *wei* sometimes) that you can transfer. For example, you will be able to transfer 123.456789456 tokens.

Comment: ok i see with the decimals i can change the decimals so decimals= 2 gives me a total supply of 30000

Comment: i appreciate your help dude, i think i understand now

Comment: a last quewstion if  you dont mind, can i specify any amount of decimals, like 2 34 5 decimals? because i thought it has to be 8 or 18 decimals?

Comment: Yes, though keep in mind that Solidity is limited to 256 bits, so a high value of `decimals` will limit your ability to perform arithmetic operations without overflowing.

Comment: `300 * 10 ** 2` indeed gives you `30000`. I wonder how come you haven't realized this up until now, since `300 * 10 ** 2 == 30000`. What might be harder to understand is that those 30000 will be considered as 300 tokens by any application which exposes your token (for example, metamask, etherscan, myetherwallet, etc), because that application will see that you have set `decimals = 2`.